# Dynamically generated select tag option not filtered by jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jstl

I dynamically generate the select tag using `jstl` like below.But I am failed to select the option in jquery.

JSP:

```
<c:forEach var="p" items="${model.multiphase}" varStatus="row">
    <select class="form-control status" name="status">
        <option value="Notyetstarted">Not Yet Started</option>
        <option value="Inprogress">InProgress</option>
        <option value="Onhold">OnHold</option>
        <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" id="upstatus_${row.index}" value="<c:out value='${p.getProjectPhase().getPhaseStatus()}'/>" />
</c:forEach>
```

the above jstl generates the below html

```
<select class="form-control status" name="status">
        <option value="Notyetstarted">Not Yet Started</option>
        <option value="Inprogress">InProgress</option>
        <option value="Onhold">OnHold</option>
        <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" id="upstatus_0" value="Closed" />
 <select class="form-control status" name="status">
        <option value="Notyetstarted">Not Yet Started</option>
        <option value="Inprogress">InProgress</option>
        <option value="Onhold">OnHold</option>
        <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" id="upstatus_1" value="Onhold" />
```

I have used below jquery for selecting the option.

```
$(".status option").each(function () {
    alert("fd");

    $(this).find("option").filter(function () {

        return $(this).val() == $("#upstatus_" + index).val();

    }).prop('selected', true);
});
```

How to preselect the value?
Any help will be greatly Appreciated!!!

Comment: This should work: `$("option",'select.status').filter(function () {
        return $(this).val() == $("#upstatus_" + index).val();
}).prop('selected', true);`

Comment: @ventkata,not worked,i have dynamic select tag

Comment: You might have other issue, try with case insensitive `$("option",'select.status').filter(function () { return $(this).val().toLowerCase() == $("#upstatus_" + index).val().toLowerCase(); }).prop('selected', true);` Also check the index you are using coming correct or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to this:

```
$(".status").each(function () {
    var that = $(this);
    $(this).find('option').filter(function (index) {
        console.log($(this).parent().next(":hidden").val());
        return $(this).val() === that.next(":hidden").val()
    }).prop('selected', true);
});
```

#### [Sample Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9d4a1zyy/)

#### [Updated Sample Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9d4a1zyy/1/)

---

`-> :` *jquery not enters in the alert.*

because you have `.each()` iteration on the option not on the select element.

---

Although you can change to this also:

```
$(".status").each(function (i) { // add a index "i" here
    $(this).find('option').filter(function () {
        return $(this).val() === $("#upstatus_"+i).val() // use that here
    }).prop('selected', true);
});
```

#### [Sample for this.](http://jsfiddle.net/9d4a1zyy/2/)

Comment: Not working i add the below code in script $(".status").each(function(index){alert("Dds");} but alert not triggered

Comment: ,worked for first row  but other rows are failed to preselect

Comment: your example has only one select but i have more select tags

Comment: Glad this worked for you, but in any case if your markup gets changed then first one with `.next()` method will failed, so in this case you can take a look at the new one below with a updated fiddle.